# Get column type per row

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a table with a few rows. The datatypes are not set in the table structure and some rows are integers while some are BLOBs.

How would I figure out what's what? I'm using the **C API**.

`sqlite3_column_type` gives me the same datatype for all rows, which isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sqlite3_column_type` is the function that gives you the actual type of the data.
2. Beware that when you get the value with the other `sqlite3_column_*` functions, sqlite converts the data it has and the type *changes* to reflect that. Ask for types before doing anything else with the row.
3. There is some logic that converts values when inserting them. Are you certain the data is what you expect? Check with `typeof` SQL function (the `sqlite3_column_type` C function and `typeof` SQL function should always return the same value).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sqlite3_column_type` I had it confused from testing a bunch of things. It turned out Navicat was being silly and thought it'd be a good idea for plain numeric values to be inserted as BLOBs.. Cheers for the info!